# Is there a way to pop up an error like 'Enter gender as M/F/T' in my trigger for multiple row insertions without affecting the correct rows?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, triggers

I am creating a table of patient database where one of the columns is Gender. When the user enters the gender as Male/Female or other, I need the system to pop up the error like 'Enter gender as M/F/T' via trigger. Although my trigger is working with single entry insertion, when I enter multile rows, it shows error message and rollsback entire transaction and correct rows also dont get inserted into the table.
I need the code to enter the correct data but only show error for wrong rows when I insert multiple values. Here is the code

P.S. I know other easy ways to enter constraint, I am practising to generate trigger with this case. Thus appreciating corrections in this error format.

```
create TRIGGER gender_trigger
ON PatientDatabase
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
     BEGIN TRY
        IF EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM INSERTED
            WHERE gender NOT IN ('M', 'F', 'T')
        )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Enter Gender as M or F or T.', 16, 1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END 
        ELSE 
        INSERT INTO PatientDatabase (PatientID,PatientName,Age,Gender,TimeOfAdmission,TimeOfDischarge)
            SELECT PatientID,PatientName,Age,Gender,TimeOfAdmission,TimeOfDischarge
            FROM INSERTED where gender in ('M', 'F', 'T')
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    throw
    END CATCH            
END;
```

Comment: Partial data entry is probably a bad idea, as well as trigger validation :) But i guess if you really want to, you can remove the rollback and just raiserror after inserting the legit values and hope you don't rollback the rest of the changes

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the database *and* with a trigger?!! This should primarily be client-side validation and a constraint in the database.

Comment: If you are inserting multiple rows in a transaction, then this is correct behavior for a transaction. A transaction takes multiple operations and groups them into (generally) a single pass/fail set. So, if you're set on a validation error as a trigger (consider also, a `check constraint`), can you adjust your insert logic to iterate one row at a time? If you go with an iterator (such as `WHILE` or `CURSOR`) and still want transactions on the group of records, look into transaction "savepoints".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of other folks have told you why this isn't a good idea, and how to more effectively do it.

If you really want to pursue this, you could try:

```
USE Master;

DROP DATABASE Demo;
GO

CREATE DATABASE Demo;
GO

USE Demo;

CREATE TABLE Person (ID BIGINT IDENTITY, Name NVARCHAR(50), Gender VARCHAR(1));
GO
CREATE TRIGGER Person_Gender
ON Person
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DECLARE @InsertedCount BIGINT;
 DECLARE @Output TABLE (Name NVARCHAR(50), Gender VARCHAR(1));
  INSERT INTO @Output (Name, Gender)
   SELECT Name, Gender
     FROM INSERTED
    WHERE Gender NOT IN ('M', 'F', 'T');
  SET @InsertedCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
  INSERT INTO Person (Name, Gender)
  SELECT Name, Gender
    FROM INSERTED 
   WHERE Gender IN ('M', 'F', 'T');
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Output)
  BEGIN
   SELECT Name, Gender  
     FROM @Output;
   RAISERROR ('The returned rows have an invalid gender. Enter Gender as M or F or T.', 1,1);
  END;
  PRINT CAST(@InsertedCount AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' row(s) affected';
  SET NOCOUNT OFF;
 END
 GO

 INSERT INTO Person (Name, Gender) VALUES
 ('Joe','X'),
 ('Paul','M'),
 ('Sue','F'),
 ('Andy','T');

 SELECT ID, Name, Gender
   FROM Person;
```

`The returned rows have an invalid gender. Enter Gender as M or F or T. Msg 50000, Level 1, State 1`

| Name | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | X |

All we're doing here is filtering the rows that are sent to the table, and returning the other, non-conforming rows, with a message.
Depending on the [severity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-ver16) and state `RAISERROR` will terminate the batch, or not.

| ID | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | M |
| 2 | Sue | F |
| 3 | Andy | T |